# Connection User and validation rules

Tags: salesforce2salesforce

I have a validation rule that prevents re-opening case after a certain period has passed.  But we'd like a Connection User from a partner org to be exempt from this rule.  The problem is, how can refer to the Connection User or the partner org in my validation rule?  The Connection User isn't a real user per se, has no role, nor profile.

Are my only options to mark these cases with a trigger on insert time and use that to refer whether this is an external or internal case?

Comment: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000006ttu

Comment: Thanks for that.  Hadn't stumbled into that solution before. Bit perplexing that this is an idea, yet contains a workaround.  Some of the stuff in that post is already implemented, like the status page on the Partner connection.

Comment: Here's a bunch more tips on S2S http://cropredysfdc.com/2014/11/17/s2s-salesforce-to-salesforce-adventures/ (written by me) with an alternative way of identifying the Connection User

Answer (score 1):

If you use Roles in your org, try excluding users that don't have a role ($UserRole.Name <> "" ). This seems to work for us (for now, at least).